# How to check object empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have got object of array. I am trying to check empty.

```
  const data = {
      test:[],
      test2:[],
      test1:["can"]
    }
```

Here is my trying code:

```
const dataObj = Object.values(data)

console.log(dataObj)
```

my output would be :

```
      const data = {
          test1:["can"]
        }
```

Comment: Do you want display they has value?

Comment: Object.keys(dataObj ).length === 0 && dataObj .constructor === Object, But where in your code you want to apply this?

Comment: Do you mean like this?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/rNVRgBL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods.

```js
const data = {
  test: [],
  test2: [],
  test1: ["can"]
}

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((obj, [k, v]) => {
  if (v && v.length) obj[k] = v;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Or with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

```js
const data = {
  test: [],
  test2: [],
  test1: ["can"]
}

const res = {};

for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (v && v.length) res[k] = v;
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061331/how-to-filter-array-of-object-to-array-of-another-objects-in-javascript can you look this ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = {
    test: [],
    test2: [],
    test1: ["can"],
    test3: ["hi"]

}


for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (value.length) {
        console.log(`${key}: not emty`)
    } else {
        console.log(`${key}: emty`)
    }

}
```